# wont create a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

```py
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/bhila/Desktop/Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks-master/SalesAnalysis/Sales_Data/Sales_April_2019.csv')

files = [file for file in os.listdir('C:/Users/bhila/Desktop/Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks-master/SalesAnalysis/Sales_Data')]
    
all_months_data = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    print(file)  
    
    df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/bhila/Desktop/Pandas-Data-Science-Tasks-master/SalesAnalysis/Sales_data/'+file)
    all_monhts_data = pd.concat([all_months_data, df])
    
all_months_data.to_csv("all_data.csv", index=False)
```

It still won't create a `all_data.csv` file.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'wont create a csv file', do you get an error? or can you simply not see the file where you expect to find it?

Comment: i do not see the created file where i expect it to be created

Comment: First argument of to_csv should be a path, so it should save your .csv in the same folder at the .py you are running, if you want it to be saved in another location you neeed to provide an abosolute or relative path

Comment: when i concat these files it shows 0 entries in the file when i do     all_months_data.info()

Comment: @JosipJuros thanks man i did not know that... found the file....and how do u suggest i provide a relative path if u would help me.   but file's empty though...all the files in the df wont concat

Comment: I wrote it in the answer. A relative path is a path from your current working directory to the desired one, while the absolute path is a path from the root folder (usually C:/) to your desired folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

According to this, 1st argument is path. From your example it will save your `.csv` in the same folder in which you are running your `.py` file from. If you want to change this to something else

```
all_months_data.to_csv("all_data.csv", index=False)
```

replace `"all_data.csv"` to an absolute or relative path to the location you want it saved to?

Answer (score 1):

If you did not get any errors, the csv file must have been created and stored in the location from where your python script is executing. If you try:

```
import os
print(os.listdir())
```

you might be able to see the file present in that dir